# how to convert pdf array buffer to pdf file using nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, httpresponse, pdfkit

Following is the pdf buffer. I want convert buffer to pdf file.

```
data = {
    "file": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            102,
            24,
            62
        ]
    },
}
res.send( data );
```

Comment: Where does the buffer come from? If you are creating it, than you should [write](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_filehandle_writefile_data_options) it into a file and send that back.

Comment: The buffer is of pdf file

Comment: Then why not just sending the file back? You can create a [readstream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream) and pipe that to the response

Comment: I was trying to send pdf file along with associated json data {status:200, fileBuffer: fileBuffer, "otherJsonData": {"a": 1, "b":2}  } but it is not possible to use res.download and res.send together, so I converted pdf file to buffer and then sent it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [res.sendFile](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) and use the header to send some data along.

```
// res.sendFile(path [, options] [, fn])

let options = {
  headers: {
      'TheDataYouWantToSend': Date.now() // for example a timestamp
  }
}

req.sendFile(absolutePathToFile, options)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: how to set custom header? it is throwing an error {
    "statusCode": 425,
    "statusMsg": "Invalid character in header content [\"dataArr\"]"
}

Comment: I am trying to pass json array in headers {"Content-Type": "application/json",
              "dataArr": [{"a": 1, "b": 2}] })

Comment: I think you can just use JSON.stringify on the array, and parse it on the frontend. Also you might not want to set the content type to json, since you are sending a file.